# Securing the cable chain on a CNC gantry

Tags: design, router, tools

I have laser cut the ends of a bicycle brake cable cable chain platform on a CNC I am building. I have looped the bicycle brake cables around one end and tucked the end of the cable through the loop. There is enough friction that the cables stay reasonably taught, though I suspect during normal use, this would sag. Does anyone have a suggestion about how to secure the ends to prevent slipping? I thought I might solder the cable together, but thought a mechanical option would be better, preferably one that would allow me to easily detach the cables should one of the wood brackets break.[image: cable chain holder bracket for bicycle brake cable shelf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the ticket. A cable stop that is 6mm in diameter should just barely fit the clearance between holes. If I alternate the orientation of the bolt on top/bottom, I should be able to tighten with a socket too. Blind dumb luck on the engineering tolerances there. $15.50 with shipping for 5.[image: Throttle cable stop with 2.2mm hole & 6mm outer diameter]

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use a product known as a split bolt. It's commonly used to join ground wire to an existing ground lead without having to break or cut the existing lead:

[image: split bolt]

I've used them to secure 1/8" diameter steel cable for various purposes. Inexpensive and common in big-box hardware stores. So many links returned from my search making it impractical to suggest any specific source.

Comment: This is the type of thing I was looking for, though the particular configuration of this linked image looks like a hassle to deal with multiple split bolts next to each other. The answer I posted below looks like it will be easier to clamp down on the wire in a tight space while maintaining contact between the wood bracket and the stop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use a cable tensioner like they use in cabled railings.

The ones on amazon seem pricey but I'm sure there's a plastic version you could get in the hardware store.

This Old House shows their usage in the railing system. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNFalmwg3nY

[image: Cable tensioner]